# Xfce Python Dbus

Tags: python, dbus

I run Xfce (Arch Linux) and I'm trying to control the power manager. I already declared the power manager but what are the methods to hibernate it and control it? Here's my code so far:

```
from pydbus import SessionBus
bus = SessionBus
power = bus.get('org.xfce.PowerManager',           '/org/xfce/PowerManager')
power.hibernate
```

And it's not working. I've tried googling it, looking at docs, and guessing every method I could think of.

Comment: You need to find the method of the systemd PowerManager for hibernation, it has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dartmouth mentioned, you need to find xfce4-power-manager's exposed methods. For that [DFeet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet) (a D-Bus debugger) will help you:

[image]

Then you can call the method (via terminal):

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply \
--dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement \
/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement \
org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Hibernate
```